# Как установить старую версию приложения в ubuntu(linux) через apt-get?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gitlab, apt-get

Какая последовательность действий при необходимости установить старую версию приложения? например мне нужно установить gitlab-ce версии 8.12.2.
На сайтах приведена инструкция по установке последней версии приложения. При чем версии gitlab-ee, а не gitlab-ce.

При применении команды

```
apt-cache show gitlab-ce
```

отобразить имеющиеся версии он пишет:

```
N: Не удалось выбрать версии из пакета «gitlab-ce», так как он полностью виртуальный
N: Не найдено ни одного пакета
```

Собственно откуда брать информацию об пакете gitlab-ce? И вообще часто возникает потребность установить старые версии, но на сайта этих приложений про них ни слова, только про самые новые версии. Непонятно кто хранит и хранит ли старые версии.
Вопрос в том, какая четкая последовательность действий по поиску более старой версии пакета?

---

Нашел в репозитории эту версию.
https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/packages/ubuntu/trusty/gitlab-ce_8.12.2-ce.0_amd64.deb

Далее выполнил команду которая указана в репозитории:

```
curl -s https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ce/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
```

Однако при попытке установки он пишет что версия не найдена:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну так идете к ним в репозиторий  и находите там подходящую версию (https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce?page=196). а дальше качаете и устанавливаете по старинке. правда скорее всего будет куча проблем (версия то очень и очень старая), но если Вам такая версия нужна, то думаю, справитесь

Comment: а как найти репозиторий конкретной программы? Эти репозитории кто хранит и поддерживает?

Comment: здесь нет единого правила. обычно гугл всегда спасает

Comment: @KoVadim
Обновил вопрос. Выполнил инструкции с сайта, однако он пишет что эта версия все равно не найдена. И самая старая версия  выводится 13.2.0-ce.0 командой apt-cache show gitlab-ce

Comment: если у Вас распоследняя убунта, то так просто не даст (https://packages.gitlab.com/app/gitlab/gitlab-ce/search?q=8.12.2&filter=all&filter=all&dist=)